# gstreamer video output on pi framebuffer without X

Tags: framebuffer

I am running the latest Jessie image on my pi2 B.  I have gstreamer-1.0 installed with gstreamer omx plugins.  gst-inspect confirms the omx plugins are installed.  I am not using the X server and need to output directly to the hdmi framebuffer.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ gst-inspect-1.0 | grep omx
omx:  omxmpeg2videodec: OpenMAX MPEG2 Video Decoder
omx:  omxmpeg4videodec: OpenMAX MPEG4 Video Decoder
omx:  omxh263dec: OpenMAX H.263 Video Decoder
omx:  omxh264dec: OpenMAX H.264 Video Decoder
omx:  omxtheoradec: OpenMAX Theora Video Decoder
omx:  omxvp8dec: OpenMAX VP8 Video Decoder
omx:  omxmjpegdec: OpenMAX MJPEG Video Decoder
omx:  omxvc1dec: OpenMAX WMV Video Decoder
omx:  omxh264enc: OpenMAX H.264 Video Encoder
omx:  omxanalogaudiosink: OpenMAX Analog Audio Sink
omx:  omxhdmiaudiosink: OpenMAX HDMI Audio Sink
```

I am unable to play any video back on the framebuffer.  I do not seem to have any video sinks installed and I cannot seem to figure out what gstreamer packages I am missing.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ gst-inspect-1.0 | grep sink
omx:  omxanalogaudiosink: OpenMAX Analog Audio Sink
omx:  omxhdmiaudiosink: OpenMAX HDMI Audio Sink
tcp:  multisocketsink: Multi socket sink
tcp:  multifdsink: Multi filedescriptor sink
tcp:  tcpserversink: TCP server sink
tcp:  tcpclientsink: TCP client sink
app:  appsink: AppSink
playback:  playsink: Player Sink
gio:  giostreamsink: GIO stream sink
gio:  giosink: GIO sink
coreelements:  filesink: File Sink
coreelements:  fdsink: Filedescriptor Sink
coreelements:  fakesink: Fake Sink
```

I know that video output to the framebuffer works, because I can use omxplayer and see the video I am trying to play.  I need gstreamer to work because I need more flexibility than omxplayer can provide.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=myvideo.mpg ! decodebin ! autovideosink
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "autovideosink"

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=myvideo.mpg ! decodebin ! fbdevsink
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "fbdevsink"
```

What am I missing to playback video on the pi framebuffer device?  Is there an omxhdmivideosink?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi did you have any luck with this? I'm having a smiilar issue with gstreamer + framebuffer on Raspbian.  Thx

Comment: no, I was not able to figure it out.  I switched to omxplayer to get a temporary implementation.  gstreamer would be the best solution once I get this answer.

Answer (score 5):

The one way you can output directly to the `frame buffer` is using `fbdevsink`, e.g.:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! fbdevsink
```

The `fbdevsink` can be found in the `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad` package.

Comment: Any experiences with this solution sometimes yielding a blank screen?  My experience is that sometimes the user can output to /dev/fb0, but other times it'll silently fail.

Comment: @mpr Yes. I had this problem on RPi 2 rev.B with Raspbian, and haven't found any solution. Only reboot helped. Though everything goes fine on RPi 3 for already an year.

Comment: Ok here's an interesting detail.  If I set the hdmi_group and hdmi_mode in config.txt, reboot, and don't use tvservice at all, fbdevsink works.  After invoking tvservice, fbdevsink no longer works.  I'm currently testing on a Raspbery Pi 3 Model B V 1.2.

Comment: Ok it looks like calls to tvservice may also need a following, matching call to fbset.  See here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=52309

Comment: Thanks. Now I have a stable behavior using this series of commands (my monitor has 1280x1024 resolution): `tvservice -o`, `tvservice -p`, `fbset -depth 8`, `fbset -g 1280 1024 1280 1024 16`